Keybase file explorer integration failed (KDE, Wayland, Dolphin)
Installed and running latest Keybase version using official manual.
It says "Keybase is enabled in your File Explorer" but there is neither mounted point, nor "Show in File Explorer", though.
Any ideas - how it can be fixed?
sudo yum install https://prerelease.keybase.io/keybase_amd64.rpm
run_keybase
keybase config set mountdir /home/madzohan/.local/share/keybase/fs

keybase --version
keybase version 6.3.1-20240604204202+8a112fbd55

on
OS:                     Nobara 39
KDE Plasma Version:     6.0.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.2.0
Qt Version:             6.6.2
Kernel Version:         6.8.12-200.fsync.fc39.x86_64 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform:      Wayland
Dolphin version:        24.05.0

$ journalctl -b | grep keybase

sudo[23329]: madzohan : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/madzohan ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/yum install https://prerelease.keybase.io/keybase_amd64.rpm
systemd[1521]: Starting keybase.service - Keybase core service...
systemd[1521]: Started keybase.service - Keybase core service.
systemd[1521]: Starting keybase-redirector.service - Keybase Root Redirector for KBFS...
keybase[23707]: 2024-07-18T16:41:55.426933+03:00 ▶ [WARN keybase json.go:81] 001 Permission denied opening config file /etc/keybase/config.json
keybase[23707]: 2024-07-18T16:41:55.426987+03:00 ▶ [WARN keybase json.go:81] 002 Permission denied opening gui config file /etc/keybase/gui_config.json
keybase[23707]: 2024-07-18T16:41:55.427004+03:00 ▶ [WARN keybase json.go:81] 003 Permission denied opening updater config file /etc/keybase/updater.json
sh[23706]: fusermount: entry for /home/madzohan/.local/share/keybase/fs not found in /etc/mtab
systemd[1521]: Started keybase-redirector.service - Keybase Root Redirector for KBFS.
systemd[1521]: Starting keybase.gui.service - Keybase GUI...
systemd[1521]: Started keybase.gui.service - Keybase GUI.
sudo[24251]: madzohan : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/madzohan ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ls /etc/keybase/config.json


$ sudo ls -lah /etc/keybase
total 4,0K
drwx------  1 root root   30 15 18:29 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 5,1K 18 16:41 ..
-rw-------  1 root root   19 15 18:29 gui_config.json

$ sudo cat /etc/keybase/gui_config.json
{
    "gui": true
}

$ keybase fs ls --rec --all /keybase
▶ ERROR RootFS cannot chroot

$ systemctl --user status kbfs.service
● kbfs.service - Keybase Filesystem service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/kbfs.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/user/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-07-18 16:41:55 EEST; 32min ago
    Process: 23706 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c fusermount -uz "$(keybase config get -d -b mountdir)" (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 23730 (kbfsfuse)
      Tasks: 14 (limit: 18908)
     Memory: 116.4M
        CPU: 4.268s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/kbfs.service
             └─23730 /usr/bin/kbfsfuse -debug -log-to-file

18 16:41:55 madnobara systemd[1521]: Starting kbfs.service - Keybase Filesystem service...
18 16:41:55 madnobara sh[23706]: fusermount: entry for /home/madzohan/.local/share/keybase/fs not found in /etc/mtab
18 16:41:55 madnobara systemd[1521]: Started kbfs.service - Keybase Filesystem service.

